# Centering a tikzpicture flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, koma-script, flow-charts

I am trying to build up a PRISMA flow chart.

I found this excellent code by @Zarko and @Sergej in an old post:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=15mm and 10mm,
    start chain=going below,
    mynode/.style = {
        draw, rectangle, align=center, text width=5cm,
        font=\small, inner sep=3ex, outer sep=0pt,
        on chain},
    mylabel/.style = {
        draw, rectangle, align=center, rounded corners, 
        font=\small\bfseries, inner sep=2ex, outer sep=0pt,
        fill=cyan!30, minimum height=38mm,
        on chain},
    every join/.style = arrow,
    arrow/.style = {very thick,-stealth}
    ] 
    \coordinate (tc);
    % the title
    \node[above=of tc,font=\bfseries] {PRISMA 2009 Flow Diagram};
    % the nodes at the top
    \node (n1a) [mynode, left=of tc]    {\# of records is identified 
        through database searching};
    \node (n1b) [mynode,right=of tc]    {\# of additional records indentified\\
        through other sources};
    % the chain in the center
    \node (n2)  [mynode, below=of tc]   {\# of records after duplicates removed};
    \node (n3)  [mynode,join]   {\# of additional records indentified\\
        through other sources};
    \node (n4)  [mynode,join]   {\# of full-text articles accessed 
        for eligibility};
    \node (n5)  [mynode,join]   {\# of studies included in qualitative synthesis};
    \node (n6)  [mynode,join]   {\# of studies included in quantitative sysntesis\\
        (meta-analysis)};
    % the branches to the right
    \node (n3r) [mynode,right=of n3]    {\# of records excluded};
    \node (n4r) [mynode,right=of n4]    {\# of full-text articles excluded,
        with reasons};
    % lines not included in join                                        
    \draw[arrow] ([xshift=+22mm] n1a.south) coordinate (a)
    -- (a |- n2.north);
    \draw[arrow] ([xshift=-22mm] n1b.south) coordinate (b)
    -- (b |- n2.north);
    \draw[arrow] (n3) -- (n3r);
    \draw[arrow] (n4) -- (n4r);
    % the labels on the left
    \begin{scope}[node distance=7mm]
        \node[mylabel,below left=-3mm and 11mm of n1a.north west]
        {\rotatebox{90}{Identification}};
        \node[mylabel]  {\rotatebox{90}{Screening}};
        \node[mylabel]  {\rotatebox{90}{Eligibility}};
        \node[mylabel]  {\rotatebox{90}{Included}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{\textbf{PRISMA flow chart}}
```

I have two problems:

1. The figure does not fit in the page: it is shifted to the right so I have some space on the left, but the nodes on the right hand side are cut.
2. I added a caption to the figure, but it displays on the following page (maybe the figure's dimensions fill up the page.

How can I move the entire figure to the left and obtain some space below for the caption?

I am using a KOMA-skript (scrbook)

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding teh documentclass as well as the relevant packages to your code. Are you sure, there is space left on the left side of your page? To check that, you can add the `showframe` package to your preamble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not bother trying to move the image into the left margin, but instead make it narrower so that it fits into the available space of your page. (Red lines in the following screenshot represent the available text area.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains}

%%% do not include in actual document
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} % <---- added figure environment
\centering % <---- added to horizontally center the flow chart
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=15mm and 10mm,
    start chain=going below,
    mynode/.style = {
        draw, rectangle, align=center, text width=3.5cm,  % <------ replaced  5cm with 3.5cm in order to make text boxes narrow enough to fit into the page
        font=\small, inner sep=3ex, outer sep=0pt,
        on chain},
    mylabel/.style = {
        draw, rectangle, align=center, rounded corners, 
        font=\small\bfseries, inner sep=2ex, outer sep=0pt,
        fill=cyan!30, minimum height=38mm,
        on chain},
    every join/.style = arrow,
    arrow/.style = {very thick,-stealth}
    ] 
    \coordinate (tc);
    % the title
    \node[above=of tc,font=\bfseries] {PRISMA 2009 Flow Diagram};
    % the nodes at the top
    \node (n1a) [mynode, left=of tc]    {\# of records is identified 
        through database searching};
    \node (n1b) [mynode,right=of tc]    {\# of additional records indentified\\
        through other sources};
    % the chain in the center
    \node (n2)  [mynode, below=of tc]   {\# of records after duplicates removed};
    \node (n3)  [mynode,join]   {\# of additional records indentified\\
        through other sources};
    \node (n4)  [mynode,join]   {\# of full-text articles accessed 
        for eligibility};
    \node (n5)  [mynode,join]   {\# of studies included in qualitative synthesis};
    \node (n6)  [mynode,join]   {\# of studies included in quantitative sysntesis\\
        (meta-analysis)};
    % the branches to the right
    \node (n3r) [mynode,right=of n3]    {\# of records excluded};
    \node (n4r) [mynode,right=of n4]    {\# of full-text articles excluded,
        with reasons};
    % lines not included in join                                        
    \draw[arrow] ([xshift=+15mm] n1a.south) coordinate (a) % <------ replaced  22mm with 15mm to adjust the horizontal placement of the arrows
    -- (a |- n2.north);
    \draw[arrow] ([xshift=-15mm] n1b.south) coordinate (b) % <------ replaced  22mm with 15mm to adjust the horizontal placement of the arrows
    -- (b |- n2.north);
    \draw[arrow] (n3) -- (n3r);
    \draw[arrow] (n4) -- (n4r);
    % the labels on the left
    \begin{scope}[node distance=7mm]
        \node[mylabel,below left=-3mm and 4mm of n1a.north west]  % <------ replaced  11mm with 4mm to decrease the space between the blue rotated boxes and teh white boxes
        {\rotatebox{90}{Identification\vphantom{g}}}; % <--------  added \vphantom{g} for equal box widths
        \node[mylabel]  {\rotatebox{90}{Screening}};
        \node[mylabel]  {\rotatebox{90}{Eligibility}};
        \node[mylabel]  {\rotatebox{90}{Included\vphantom{g}}};  % <--------  added \vphantom{g} for equal box widths
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{PRISMA flow chart} % <------ used \caption instead of \captionof
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! And thank you for showing the use of the frame: it could be useful in several occasions.

Comment: Just to understand better: you changed the text width to 3.5, then the labels (mylabel,below left=-3mm and 4mm) to 4 mm instead of 11. How did you manage to allow the caption in the same page?

Comment: @FabioCampanile: I just updated my answer to add some comments on the changes I made to the code.